# t-sql defect when selecting an non-existent column from a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I've running the following SQL against a SQL Server 2012 database:

```
CREATE TABLE #CrossDatabaseMatch
(
    Id1 INT
   ,Id2 INT
)

--populate #CrossDatabaseMatch with some ids

--add more ids but don't include any of the ids we have already got a match for
INSERT INTO 
    #CrossDatabaseMatch (Id1, Id2)
SELECT
    st.ID
    ,tt.SecurityKey
FROM
    dbo.SourceTable st
INNER JOIN
    Database2.Datamart.TargetTable tt ON st.Identifier = tt.Identifier
WHERE
    st.ID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM #CrossDatabaseMatch)
```

This SQL runs despite the fact that the column `Id` does not exist in the `#CrossDatabaseMatch` table

When I isolate and run the `SELECT id FROM #CrossDatabaseMatch` query in the same session I get the error I expected:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'id'.

Interestingly when I change the name of the column (let's say `SELECT [some_non_existant_id] FROM \#CrossDatabaseMatch`) I get an error from my query

Anyone know why SQL Server is doing this? Is there something special about the column name `id` for temp tables?

Obviously I know that `SELECT id FROM #CrossDatabaseMatch` code is busted - it came from a typo when I was first writing the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845281/sql-delete-clears-the-table-instead-of-erroring

Comment: This is also why it's a good practice to always alias your tables and then use that alias against every column.